# Proving that a function is injective

Tags: functions, proof-explanation

> Let $X$ and $Y$ be sets and let $f: X\to Y$ be a function.
>   Suppose that $U_1,\, U_2\subseteq X$.
>
> Show that if $f$ is injective then $f\left((U_1 \cup U_2)^c\right)= f(U_1^c)\cap f(U_2^c)$

I'm not exactly sure how to go about this proof. My first thought was that the left hand side is De Morgans Law but I'm not sure how to write this as an actual proof and how that can show it is an injection?

Comment: The problem does not ask you to show that $f$ is injective. It's one of the hypothesis.

Comment: So I can assume f is injective and by using De Morgans Laws it is enough to show that the two are equal?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

HINT: Using the injectivity of $f$, can you show that $f(A\cap B)=f(A)\cap f(B)$?

If so, then you're done, since by De Morgan's laws $(U_1\cup U_2)^c=U_1^c\cap U_2^c$.

---

To see why injectivity might be necessary to show the above fact: we'll always have $f(A\cap B)\subseteq f(A)\cap f(B)$, but the converse may fail for non-injective $f$ - for instance, if $f(x)=17$ (for $x\in\mathbb{R}$), then $$f(\{0\}\cap \{1\})=f(\emptyset)=\emptyset$$ but $$f(\{0\})\cap f(\{1\})=\{17\}\cap\{17\}=\{17\}.$$

Comment: A good exercise, after you've done this, is to show that this exactly characterizes the injective functions: $f:X\rightarrow Y$ is injective iff $\forall A, B\subseteq X$, we have $f(A\cap B)=f(A)\cap f(B)$.